# Checked function not working for cloned div

Tags: jquery

I cloned a div which contained checkboxes, the below function works for original div but it fails to react to cloned div checkboxes.
Code is not so easy to understand , that's why not sharing here.
What conceptual mistake I am doing. Please help!!1

```
$(".checkboxes").change( function(){
if(this.checked) 
{
//something
}
});
```

Comment: you should use event delegate to add change event to the checkbox.

Comment: There are trillions of similar questions. Look for delagated events. `$(document).on('change', '.checkboxes', function() { ... }`

Comment: Downvote for not caring to accept an answer, write a comment or give any feedback to the ones that try to help you.

Comment: not voted bacause none of the answers were good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you load the change() function on load, and afterwards you clone some of the elements. If you want to have events on dynamically loaded content, then you have to call the event function again or fire the event on a wrapper that is static like this:

```
// .checkboxes-wrapper is loaded at the beginning and it's appended with the new checkboxes
$('.checkboxes-wrapper').on('click', '.checkboxes', function(){
    // do your stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[There is a demo](http://jsbin.com/rekati/edit?html,js,output) to simulate what your issus.

```
$("body").on('change','.checkboxes',function(){
  if(this.checked) 
  {
    alert('!')
  }
});

$('.checkboxes').clone().appendTo('body');
```